# Google Map Pin with city/country field

Tags: google-maps

I know it's possible to drop pins on a google map with the LAT/LONG variables. I was wondering if it's possible to drop pins with city/country fields. I have a registration form that allows the user to enter his address and wondering if any of those address variables (city, state, country, postal/zip code) can be used to create the pin on the map.. As opposed to asking the client to search and enter the LAT / LONG?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use geocoding services to convert the address to a lat/long. You can try [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), or some other such as [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/)